# Android Google Maps - show half the earth

Tags: android, dictionary

I want to display a google map in my application that shows one complete half of the globe, containing two markers that are about 20,000 km from one another in the same view.

I tried using the property getMinZoomLevel(), but it's not sufficient - it shows the first marker surrounded by an area only about the size of half a continent. Is there any way of getting the wide view that I want?

Code example for last known user location (one of the markers), where zoomLevel is getMinZoomLevel():

```
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(getCameraPositionFromLocationWithZoom(UserLocation.getInstance(App.getInstance().getApplicationContext()).getLastKnownLocation(), zoomLevel)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like.

```
private LatLngBounds bounds;
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

        builder.include(pointA);
        builder.include(pointB);
        //and other latlng points as you like...
        bounds = builder.build();

map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(
                            bounds, 20));
```

animateCamera animates the camera to specific point location. if you have more then one point (LatLngBounds) it will expand the map to be visible all points.

Hope to be helpful.